# Nested iteration in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the difference (if any) between two code fragments below?

Example from Ch7 of Programming i Scala

```
def grep(pattern: String) = 
  for (
    file <- filesHere
    if file.getName.endsWith(".scala");
    line <- fileLines(file)
    if line.trim.matches(pattern)
  ) println(file + ": " + line.trim)
```

and this one

```
def grep2(pattern: String) = 
  for (
    file <- filesHere
    if file.getName.endsWith(".scala")
  ) for (
    line <- fileLines(file)
    if line.trim.matches(pattern)
  ) println(file + ": " + line.trim)
```

Or

```
for (i <- 1 to 2)
  for (j <- 1 to 2)
    println(i, j)
```

and

```
for (
  i <- 1 to 2;
  j <- 1 to 2
) println(i, j)
```

Comment: I think the variants only differ by syntax. Section 6.19 of the Scala Language Specification (v. 2.8) defines how for loops are rewritten. http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=97

Comment: Search for questions about Scala and yield. One of them should explain exactly how `for` works in Scala.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In this case there is no difference. However when using yield there is:

```
for (
  i <- 1 to 2;
  j <- 1 to 2
) yield (i, j)
```

Will give you a sequence containing `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,1)` and `(2,2)`.

```
for (i <- 1 to 2)
  for (j <- 1 to 2)
    yield (i, j)
```

Will give you nothing, because it generates the sequence `(i,1)`, `(i,2)` on each iteration and then throws it away.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes it is also useful to output a multi dimensional collection (for example a matrix of table):

```
for (i <- 1 to 2) yield for (j <- 1 to 2) yield (i, j)
```

Will return:

```
Vector(Vector((1,1), (1,2)), Vector((2,1), (2,2)))
```