# Idiomatic Scala for nested loop

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to write idiomatic scala code to loop through two lists of lists, and to generate a new list containing only the differences of the two lists.

In procedural Scala I would do something like this:

```
val first: List[List[Int]]  = List(List(1,2,3,4,5),List(1,2,3,4,5),  List(1,2,3,4,5))
val second: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1,2,3,4,5),List(1,23,3,45,5),List(1,2,3,4,5))

var diff: List[String] = List[String]()
for (i <- List.range(0, first.size)){
  for (j <- List.range(0, first(0).size)){
    println(first(i)(j) + " " + second(i)(j))
    if (first(i)(j) != second(i)(j)) diff = diff ::: (s"${second(i)(j)}" :: Nil)
  }
}
```

Of course I do not like this, I have attempted to write a solution using for comprehension, but without success.

The closest thing I could get to was this:

```
for {(lf,ls) <- (first zip second) } yield if (lf == ls) lf else ls
```

but from that for comprehension I can not generate a list of String being of a different type from the input one.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are first and second supposed to be List(List(1,2,3,4,5),List(1,2,3,4,5), List(1,2,3,4,5))?

Comment: probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634897/nested-iteration-in-scala

Comment: @alva Could you please make your code compile. The type is still wrong, first and second is not of type Int. Also in the example diff is a immutable list assigned to an val, so it is never updated.

Comment: @Tyth, no I don't think is a duplicate. I do understand the difference between for and list comprehension. What I am asking here, is for any suggestion on how to write nested for loops in idiomatic scala, if there is an idiomatic approach.

Comment: It would probably help if you provided sample inputs and outputs :)

Comment: You could use multiple generators in same for comprehension: `for { i <- ...; j <- ...} yield ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic Scala would be something like this:

```
(
  for {
    (row1, row2) <- (first, second).zipped   // go through rows with the same index
    (value1, value2) <- (row1, row2).zipped  // go through values with the same indexes
    if value1 != value2                      // leave only different values in the list
  } yield value2.toString
).toList
```

It's better to use `zipped`, than `zip` here, because `zipped` doesn't produce the whole zipped `List` in memory.

Also, you have to do `toList` in the end, due to a quirk in type inference.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this produces the same results

```
val diff = for {
  firstInner <- first
  v1 <- firstInner
  secondInner <- second
  v2 <- secondInner
} yield if (v1 != v2) s"$v2}"

println(diff2 mkString ", ") // prints 23, 45
```

But this ofcourse fails with IndexOutOfBoundsException if the array sizes isn't of the same size.